# How to Rotate a Window's Orientation?

Tags: windows-7, windows

It's fairly easy to rotate the entire desktop's orientation on MS Windows. However, I'm looking for a way to rotate a single window's orientation. Are there any easy tricks to do this?

Comment: Just curious, do you have any specific reason to do that?

Comment: I'd be very interested in knowing what reasons you have for wanting to do this.

Comment: Probably makes it easier to edit rotated pics :)

Comment: You can rotate pictures on the picture editor, even Microsoft Paint, from Windows 95 is able to rotate images..... Still doesn't convinced me.

Comment: It's a fairly obscure use: I'm programming an android app and on the emulator sometimes you want different screen orientations. Unfortunately, when the orientation is changed in the emulator it also appears sideways on the screen. The problem is really with the emulator but I though this may be a possible solution.

Comment: My usecase is VERY simple: using windows as a smart table require to be able to rotate windows' application. Actually everyone is reinventing the wheel in a dedicated app

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have several monitors and you can rotate one of them, you could always use Magnifier with a magnification of 1 to copy the active window to a different monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rotate each application window individually, however, if you have **multiple monitors** you can **rotate each one in a different orientation**. This way, you can move the application that needs to be in portrait orientation, for example, and keep it on the portrait oriented screen. Keep the windows you wish to be in normal orientation on the screen with normal orientation.

If you have NVIDIA graphics card, NVIDIA Control Panel allows this:

[image]

Even though my computer doesn't use it, I am pretty sure ATI's [Catalyst Control Center](http://sites.amd.com/us/game/downloads/Pages/crossfirex-app-profiles.aspx) also has this feature.

A third party application called [iRotate](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Video-Tweak/iRotate.shtml) also allows individual window rotation and is free:

> iRotate is a free screen rotation utility, providing administrators,
>   end-users and manufacturers of pivoting monitors with a standardized,
>   simple mechanism to control screen orientation across multiple
>   monitors, operating systems and graphics cards.

Comment: Did you mean individual window rotation or individual screen rotation there?